# Junit for SOAP service call

Tags: soap, junit, mockito, junit4, soap-client

I have the below client side code to invoke a SOAP based webservice.
I want to write a junit for the below code which will not invoke the actual web service but use some mock calls.

```
URL url = null;
        try {
        url = new URL("someendpoint");
        QName qname = new QName("someURI", "someservicename");
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
        forData1PortType = service.getPort(ForData1PortType.class);
        ForReferenceDataType req2= buildACompleteForDataRequest();
        ResponseGetForDataType referenceData1=null;
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) forData1PortType;
            bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "someendpoint");
            Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(forData1PortType);
             referenceData1 = forData1PortType.getReferenceData1(req2);
             
        }
```

Comment: Than simply use another endpoint (the mock service related one) for your junit tests.

Comment: I meant i want to Mock the URI and calls to webservice using Mockito/Powermock.